# How to open the Recycle Bin from the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, recycle-bin

How do I open the Recycle Bin from the command line?

I'd be very glad if there is a built-in Windows command.

Comment: Do you mean the *Recycle Bin* window or just the directory? Does it have to be for all drives or a specific one?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

### Command line

On the command line, type

```
start shell:RecycleBinFolder
```

It is not case sensitive, so you can just type `start shell:recyclebinfolder`.

### Run dialog

An alternative is to use the [Run dialog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_command) (menu Start/Run or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) - there is less to type. Type

```
shell:RecycleBinFolder
```

and press OK (or hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

### It is portable!

This method works on all versions of Windows, at least back to [Windows 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_2000).

Comment: [More shell shortcuts](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/94-more-secret-windows-shortcuts/1630) (94).

Comment: Worked in Windows 10!

Comment: [complete shell:commands](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/)

Answer (score 41):

(Depending on the OS and filesystem, the directory may be `$Recycle.bin`, `Recycled`, or `Recycler`.)

- To open the Recycle Bin window (showing deleted objects on all drives):

  `C:\> start ::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}`

  or
  `C:\> start shell:RecycleBinFolder`

  or
  `C:\> start C:\$Recycle.bin`
- To list deleted objects on a specific drive:

  `C:\> dir /s/a <driveletter>:\$Recycle.Bin`

  (NB, the original filenames will not be shown in this mode.)

Comment: In windows 7 `start C:\$Recycle.bin` just gave me an empty directory. I needed to use `start shell:RecycleBinFolder`

Comment: That command does not show files in this directory, because they are Super Hidden files. You must use a Super Hidden solution. Go to: Tools > Folder Options > View and select 'Show hidden files folders and drives', and untick 'Hide protected operating system files'.

Answer (score 20):

You can open the Recycle Bin window by using its [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier):

```
explorer ::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
```

Comment: This works in Windows 7, in a command window. And it opens the Recycle Bin normally: i.e. it shows you the original names of the files.

Answer (score 12):

This should work. Tested on Windows 7 successfully.

Open a command prompt and enter

```
CD \$Recycle.Bin
```

Comment: Cool! How do you view files in RecycleBin that way? dir doesn't work for me. Are you also able to empty recycle bin?

Comment: In Windows 7, to view the files, at the command prompt type the following (although, if the Recycle Bin contains a lot of files, the results will possibly scroll off your screen) - but this method will not show you the original filenames: DIR /A /S

Comment: To save the list to a log file, type the following: DIR /A /S > C:\LOG.TXT

Comment: I get `Set-Location: Cannot find path 'D:\.Bin' because it does not exist.`

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous 'run' commands for Recycle Bin worked on my Windows 10 machine. The `start shell:RecycleBinFolder` from inside the command window worked. I could not however find a way to have the system display the usual desktop icon. None of the solutions worked. I was however able to re-create the icon by making an Internet Explorer shortcut:

```
Target = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" shell:RecycleBinFolder
```

And then changing the icon to the expected icon by browsing the shell icon DLL file. I now have it back...

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Windows button</kbd> on keyboard + <kbd>R</kbd>;
then type "`shell:RecycleBinFolder`"
and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:
This will take you into the Recycle bin folder and shows the deleted items.

Items deleted using "<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>" won't be available in Recycle bin because they are permanently deleted. These items can be recovered using  data recovery software like Easerus data recovery

Tried and worked perfectly on Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: The bit about `Shift + Delete` was new to the thread and relevant (IMHO).